# Failed to define 'Time extraction pattern in filename' on Pixel Extraction (SeaDAS 7.2)

Tags: pixel, extract

I want to do pixel extraction by using SeaDAS 7.2 for more than 365 datasets. 
This my dataset input filename:

```
Input Filename list:
2014-01-01_INDESO_BIO_1dAV-RT.nc
2014-01-02_INDESO_BIO_1dAV-RT.nc
2014-01-03_INDESO_BIO_1dAV-RT.nc
.....
```

How to define 'time extraction pattern in filename' so for each input dataset will produce separated output data that have the same filename:

```
Output Filename list:
2014-01-01_INDESO_BIO_1dAV-RT.txt
2014-01-02_INDESO_BIO_1dAV-RT.txt
2014-01-03_INDESO_BIO_1dAV-RT.txt
.....
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already resolve my problem by using R `raster package`. This is my code:

```
 # define xy coordinate
 # xy can be a single point or data frame
 xy <- SpatialPoints(cbind(long, lat)) 
 pixel <- extract(raster(raster_filename, varname='variabel_name'), xy)
```